# On every snippet with Privacy Badger: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window'

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-snippets

It's been bothering me for some time. Every snippet I try to run will output an error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

#### Example

```js
console.log("Hello world!");
```

#### Illustration

[image: Console output shows the error message above as well as the file name, line and column numbers.]

#### Environment

Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100 on macOS High Sierra.
[Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) 2018.10.3.1
[HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) 2018.9.19

Comment: Yea, that's completely privacy badger bein overzealous. I don't think this is something SO should (or maybe even can) fix.

Comment: (The official version is *["Hello, World!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)*.)

Comment: Sorry for getting to this late, but the issue was PB being a little overzealous.

Comment: @TimPost OK, I tested PB update and the error is gone. Good thing that we reported the issue to PB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrivacyBadger fixed this in version 2018.12.05.